# Find equity for a move Backgammon

Tags: algorithm, evaluation, montecarlo

I would like to know if there is a formula to calculate the equity of a board. Let's suppose we have a board like:

[image]

The dice values are 3 and 6. How would I find the best move in this situation?

I also found [a website](http://www.gamercafe.com/monte/eval/), I want to make an algorithm like this website. It is a Monte-Carlo algorithm.

Comment: Have you already solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating the equity of a backgammon possition is not a simple task. The most successful approaches have been with **neural network** that teaches itself through trial and error.

Take a look at [gnubg](http://www.gnubg.org/) for a good example of a strong backgammon engine that makes use of neural networks for possition evaluation. It's open source.